# In which namespace would one implement operator<< for STL containers to enable debugging boost::spirit semantic attributes?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

If one wants to debug boost::spirit grammars

(using BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG and BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE)

AND one wants to see the values of semantic attributes implemented using STL containers, one has to provide operator<< implementations for these STL containers.

Since it is "frowned upon" to implement these operators in the namespace std, where should one implement them?

The same question applies to `boost::flyweights::flyweight<std::vector<something> >`.

Answer (score 1):

In the namespace that declares your AST types.

There's a reason that all examples introduce AST types in their own namespace.

[ADL lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) looks in to all asociated namespaces, which includes (recursively) the associated namespaces of template type arguments.

E.g. [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86bdd719dfd7593c)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Ast {
    struct X {
        std::string id;
        double value;
    };

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<X> const& xs) {
        for (auto& [id, value] : xs)
            os << "{" << quoted(id) << "," << value << "}";
        return os;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Ast::X> v{
        {"one", 1.111},
        {"two", 2.222},
        {"three", 3.333},
        {"four", 4.444},
    };

    std::cout << v;
}
```

Output

```
{"one",1.111}{"two",2.222}{"three",3.333}{"four",4.444}
```

You can even generalize this for any type in the associated namespace:

```
namespace Ast {
    struct X {
        std::string id;
        double value;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) {
            return os << "{" << quoted(x.id) << "," << x.value << "}";
        }
    };

    template <typename T> static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
        for (auto& el : v)
            os << el;
        return os;
    }
}
```

### Spirit Specific

In the case of Qi debugging, you don't need to provide the vector printing at all because the library implements it. What's more, if your struct is Fusion adapted you don't need to do anything as Spirit knows how to debug-print those.

You can even do the inverse: you can leverage Fusion printing outside of Spirit. I often do this by simply doing

```
using boost::fusion::operator<<;
```

inside my AST namespace. Do it *after* you implement any manual `operator<<` to prevent infinite recursion bugs. (See [CPPTTCG](https://accu.org/bookreviews/2003/walker_506/) or e.g. [POI](https://duckduckgo.com/?sites=cppreference.com&q=%22point+of+instantiation%22&ia=web)).

It gives the default Fusion output:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13b1c50afed2c2fe)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Ast {
    struct X {
        std::string id;
        double value;
    };

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;

    template <typename T> static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v) {
        for (auto& el : v)
            os << el;
        return os;
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::X, id, value)

int main() {
    std::vector<Ast::X> v{
        {"one", 1.111},
        {"two", 2.222},
        {"three", 3.333},
        {"four", 4.444},
    };

    std::cout << v;
}
```

Printing

```
(one 1.111)(two 2.222)(three 3.333)(four 4.444)
```

Comment: This means, that one cannot use

`std::vector<std::pair<boost::flyweights::flyweight<std::string>, bool> >`

as an attribute?

Or just plain `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: Huh. You can obviously use that as an attribute type. Whether you should is another matter (hint: no!). What you seem to care about is automatic debug attribute dumping, which is quite unrelated. Use whatever fixes that - it's for debug anyways.

Comment: Indeed the inability to overload operators for primitive types (double) oftentimes standard library types (std::string) is a wellkown "limitation" that presumably stems from legacy C compatibility once again (story of our lives). It should just inform your design choices when designing your library/interface types.